# Is it possible to treat an mmap file as a bytes object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dropbox-api, mmap, large-files

Consider the following code, where `big_file` is the path to a file that **will not fit in memory**.

```
f = os.open(big_file, os.O_RDONLY)
data = mmap.mmap(f, 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
```

At this point, `data` behave like a string with slice notation or normal file operations. However, I am programming against an API which expects an object of type `bytes` to be passed in, and gives the following error if I try to pass the variable `data`.

```
TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class 'mmap.mmap'>
```

For small files, I cannot simply pass in `data.read()` or even skip the `mmap` altogether, but for large files, this will cause a `MemoryError`.

**Is there a way to wrap or cast the `mmap` object so it can be used as  `bytes` by the API?**

Comment: Which API? Some "only" works with specific types :} Also, what Python version?

Comment: Does the API being used require the full input of the mmap'd file as a `bytes`?  If so the arbitrarily large bytes object must be passed into it right?  Do you have access to the source code of this API?

Comment: APIs that properly support the buffer protocol should, on Python 3 at least, accept an `mmap`, or a wrapped view of part of one using `memoryview`. IIRC, it didn't support the buffer protocol on Python 2 though, so you're stuck there.

Comment: Is this the Dropbox API? If so, it's hard-coded to reject anything but `bytes` and `None`.

Comment: There may still be ways to work around that, but to have a working solution will require the complete understanding of how this API call uses that bytes object, and one may then attempt to feed it a duckpunched `bytes` like object to it and see if that works.

Comment: Sounds like you need to be talking with the developers of the third-party library you're using.

Comment: @user2864740, I've tagged the Python version; the API is a Dropbox's file_upload API.

Comment: @Blender, Nice guess, I've updated the tag!

Comment: Looks like [this line in the API](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/1e6cd323a342095c461c4c5a806d3b9e316600d8/dropbox/dropbox.py#L401) ultimately caused the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docstring for the API you're using](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/blob/b5b4d012d26b739bb7b55d3c3f661be26d04dfe1/dropbox/base.py#L2077) says right at the top:

> Do not use this to upload a file larger than 150 MB. Instead, create an upload session with `files_upload_session_start`.

Assuming your computer has more than 150 MB of free memory, mmap won't help you here.  You need to use the API they recommend (which supports chunked uploads where you send one piece at a time).

Comment: `help(files_upload)` in Python would have shown it to you immediately.

Comment: Good to know; I also finally found the [full docs](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#module-dropbox.dropbox) on that API.